# Bitmap compress grainy image after saving

Tags: android, bitmap, android-glide

I'm performing a transformation on an image via Glide transformation, setting it as a background to a view with a black background, then saving it the device as a PNG. The view looks like this:

[image]

After compressing it and saving it as a PNG, it looks like this:

[image]

Ignoring the size and background difference, notice the graininess around the edges. This is persisted after the save. The PNG is the correct size as the original image so no scaling was performed. How do I prevent this from happening? The code to compress is:

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + String.valueOf(num) + ".png");
OutputStream os = null;
try {
   os = new FileOutputStream(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
```

Properties set to the bitmap were:

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
b.setHasAlpha(true);
```

Things I've tried:

- Using WEBP; same issue.
- Saving the view and building a drawing cache,
  then saving that bitmap. Again, same issue.
- Can't use JPEG since I need the alpha layer.

It seems like the compression to PNG can't handle bright colors.

**Update:**

Using RGB_565 instead of ARGB_8888 removes the graininess but adds black to the outside, since there's no alpha layer. Seems like the compression can't handle it if there are any alpha pixels.

Comment: What transformation do you perform? Your source image attached to the question is 254x266 and your transformed image is 180x180. So do you really do some resizing? If so, how exactly you do it? Resizing especially one that doesn't preserve aspect ratio might be a source of some artifacts.

Comment: @sergr Blur transformation and an edge detection one. Ignore the sizes of these. I used this one  from the internet as an example.

Comment: One more thing related to resizing: what is RGB color of your transparent pixels (i.e. how you convert your black into transparent)? If you do such a resizing it might matter, see http://www.adriancourreges.com/blog/2017/05/09/beware-of-transparent-pixels/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. If your example images are real result of your app, why the sizes of the source and the result are not the same? There are only two alternatives: you do resizing or those images are not real. So which one is true?

Comment: @sergr the first image is a screen shot of what the bitmap looks like before compression on the phone. The 2nd is the saved image after compression. The point is to show that compression creates discoloration around the edges

Comment: Am I right that you are searching for the source of "discoloration"? I suggest that just resizing of the image might be the source. If you are absolutely sure that your application doesn't do any resizing, it makes sense to put into your question real source and result images so everyone can see just artifacts introduced by your app (without additional artifacts introduced by resizing of one or both images).

Comment: @sergr yes the discoloration. No resizing. setBit

Comment: @sergr setBitmap to view.. no problem. Compress that bitmap, get from device, then set that image... discolored

Comment: putting it otherwise, can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `BitmapFactory.decodeFile`

```
String filePath = context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + String.valueOf(num) + ".png";

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
options.inDither = false;

BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
```

Alternatively, you can use `createScaledBitmap` method, it has a flag where you can set if the scaled image should be filtered or not. That flag improves the quality of the bitmap.

```
boolean shouldFilter = false;
bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, desiredWidth, desiredHeight, shouldFilter);
```